# Trying to print Avery L7173 labels with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, label, mailing

I need a solution to produce mailing labels (Avery L7173) for a list of 2500 address entries.

On the backend we have Linux Server with PHP. Python is an option. No X window.

As we have never done this, we dont know if we should go with a PDF classe or the Open Office library. We have found lots of direction by googling around but having the feedback of someone who has done it would be great time saver.

Sincerely
py

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using FPFP library to generate the PDF and then printing. Setting the co-ordinates for something like this shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to check [this code](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script29.php) using [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/). In this library, there is code for different formats.